# Combinatorics with anagrams

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the word **MONUMENTO**. How many anagrams can be formed as long as **E** and **T** are always together?

Here's how I went about solving it (it seemed simple enough):

> --> There are $9$ letters in **MONUMENTO**
>
> --> Let  **E** and **T** form a block. So there are $8$ available spaces for letters. That yields $8!$.
>
> --> Account for the permutations between **E** and **T**: $8! \cdot 2!$
>
> --> The letters **M** , **N** and **O** appear twice each, so: $\frac{8!\cdot 2!}{2!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!}$

In conclusion, the result should be $10080$ possible anagrams. However, the solution for this problem states $20160$ which means I'm dividing  by one too many $2!$. But my reasoning seems right. If I'm mistaken, then where and why?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your calculation.

Comment: In the same exercise I'm asked to calculate all possible anagrams without restriction. the solution is 9!/2!. It seems to assume that 2! covers every pair of repeated letter. This is wrong, isn't it? We're supposed to devide 2! by each pair?

Comment: You are correct, again the official answer seems wrong.  What's especially puzzling is that the error here doesn't seem to be the same as the error in the first part.  I mean, if (say) you didn't notice that there were two $N's$ then you'd get what they got for the first part.  But then you'd still have two factors of $2!$ for the second part.

Answer (score 1):

If the letters $E,T$ have to be consecutive, $ET$ can be considered as a single character, hence you have to count the anagrams of 
$M^2\, O^2\, N^2\, U\, E\!T$ which are $\frac{8!}{2!2!2!1!1!}=7!=5040$. Twice that if $TE$ is also allowed.