# In how many different ways can we make a flag of $5$ stripes if we have have $2$ red stripes, $2$ white stripes and $3$ green stripes?

Tags: combinatorics

The main problem that I am encountering is the fact that there is an unequal number of stripes. It can be done schematically but is quite exhausting.

We have $3$ options for the first stripe. Still $3$ for the second, but we can have $2$ or $3$ for the third stripe, and thus a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elementary counting should work here. We know at least one of the stripes has to be green ($G$). So we have to choose $4$ stripes from $2$ G, $2$ R and $2$ W colors.

Keeping one $G$ aside,

i) If we pick two $G$, we can then pick $RR, WW, RW$.

ii) If we pick one $G$, we can then pick $RRW, WWR$.

iii) If we pick no $G$, we then have only choice of $RRWW$.

So for (i), you can now arrange them to make $2 \cdot \frac{5!}{3! 2!} + \frac{5!}{3!} = 40 \ $ flags.

Similarly you can find for others.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$?

Comment: Paul, are you familiar with permutations of like items? In first case, we have $3$ green and either two red, two white or one white one red. To permute $3$ green and $2$ red, you will have $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ ways. Same for $3$ green and $2$ white. For $3$ green, $1$ red and $1$ white, it is simply $\frac{5!}{3!1!1!}$ ways. Can you do (ii) and (iii) similarly?

Comment: Yes, this helps! I was familiar, but just needed a bit of brushing up. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @MathLover Your answer is amazing. I love it!

Comment: @RobertZ thank you for your kind words.

Comment: @Aqua I went through the answer. I think even if that sum is even, it does not prove that there cannot be odd number of edges within each of the two groups of vertices but I may be completely wrong as this is just on the basis of few minutes I spent thinking through it and it is also possible I did not comprehend your solution properly.

Comment: Thanks..........

Answer (score 4):

Hint. There is at least a green stripe G, so we distinguish 3 cases:

1. If we have one G then the other stripes are RRWW. In this case, the number of different flags is $\frac{5!}{1!2!2!}$.
2. If we have two Gs then the other stripes are RWW or RRW. In this case, the number of different flags is ??
3. If we have three Gs then the other stripes are RR or WW or RW. In this case, the number of different flags is ?? + ??

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't follow you in $\frac{5!}{1!2!2!}$.

Comment: @Paul You have to compute the number of anagrams of the word GRRWW. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123154/combinatorics-with-anagrams